# Passing an instance to __init__. Is this a good idea?

Tags: python, class, oop, instance

Suppose I have a simple class like this:

```
class Class1(object):
  def __init__(self, property):
    self.property = property
  def method1(self):
    pass
```

An instances of Class1 returns a value that can be used in other class:

```
class Class2(object):
  def __init__(self, instance_of_class1, other_property):
    self.other_property = other_property
    self.instance_of_class1 = instance_of_class1
  def method1(self):
    # A method that uses self.instance_of_class1.property and self.other_property
```

This is working. However, I have the feeling that this is not a very common approach and maybe there are alternatives. Having said this, I tried to refactor my classes to pass simpler objects to Class2, but I found that passing the whole instance as an argument actually simplifies the code significantly. In order to use this, I have to do this:

```
instance_of_class1 = Class1(property=value)
instance_of_class2 = Class2(instance_of_class1, other_property=other_value)
instance_of_class2.method1()
```

This is very similar to the way some R packages look like. Is there a more "Pythonic" alternative?

Comment: Give your `Class1` instances a `make_class2(**kwargs)` method?

Comment: In my case, I don't want to do that because `Class1` is useful on its own, so I don't want to have a method that is not entirely relevant to the main use of `Class1`. It just happens that `Class2` could benefit itself a lot from having some properties of `Class1`.

Comment: Its normal to pass one class instance to another. Look at the standard python APIs that take open file objects, dicts, lists and etc... they are class instances too. It just means that Class2 intends to use Class1 objects in its implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with doing that, though in this particular example it looks like you could just as easily do

```
instance_of_class2 = Class2(instance_of_class1.property, other_property=other_value).
```

But if you find you need to use other properties/methods of `Class1` inside of `Class2`, just go ahead and pass the whole `Class1` instance into `Class2`. This kind of approach is used all the time in Python and OOP in general. Many common design patterns call for a class to take an instance (or several instances) of other classes: Proxy, Facade, Adapter, etc.

Comment: That is exactly my situation. There are quite a few properties from Class1 that would be useful to Class2. Great to know it is used commonly. Since I was doubtful about this, I glanced at some Github repositories, but I couldn't find an example. Maybe I didn't search thoroughly?